# Aurelia fetch client TS2304: Cannot find name 'URLSearchParams'

Tags: aurelia-fetch-client

After adding aurelia fetch client to my project i am getting the below exception when i am running `au run`

```
/node_modules/aurelia-fetch-client/dist/aurelia-fetch-client.d.ts(73,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'URLSearchParams'.
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

After i installed URLSearchParams following this [link](https://github.com/aurelia/fetch-client/issues/71) the error went away.

typings install github:RomkeVdMeulen/URLSearchParams --global --save

Answer (score 1):

You have to import URLSearchParams from @angular/http

```
import {URLSearchParams} from '@angular/http';
```

[Doc here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/URLSearchParams-class.html)